# Left Ctrl key swapped with Fn key?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I used **`xev`** to try to capture the keycode, but I don't get any output from it. I get output for the rest of the keys I checked. This happened after my system froze (likely the fault of VirtualBox) so I wonder if it has anything to do with it.

**UPDATE**:

I just found out that it's functionality is actually swapped with that of <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (the special key that allow me, for example, to press it in combination with another to change screen brightness, speaker loudness, ...). How do I swap it back?

Note that before discovering that this was merely a key swap, I actually did a reinstall in desperation, and even poked around the (badly-designed) BIOS interface (this is a **HP Probook 4350s**) to see if I screwed up with anything.

Comment: Are you on the host or guest? Is VirtualBox still involved here? If so what is your Host-Key? If it's the left control, it grabs that at a pretty low level, possibly before input gets sent on to X.

Comment: This happens even with VirtualBox uninstalled (which I did just to make sure it wasn't responsible), and my Host key is the Right Ctrl

Comment: If you log into an unconfigured account, does the key work? If you switch to a text console and run `showkey` and press that key, do you get any output? If you boot from a live CD, does the key work?

Comment: The `Fn` key is usually handled by the BIOS, at a low level where the OS can't get at. Try unplugging the computer and pulling out the battery. If that fails, poke around the BIOS some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My BIOS software/hardware must be flaky: my laptop was switched off for some hours, and the keys were swapped back on restart.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I resolved the issue following the steps mentioned below:

1. Turned off the machine
2. Removed **both** A/C power and **Battery** and waited for few seconds
3. Attached battery, and turned on the machine..

This solved my problem. I didn't wait for more than few seconds before turning on machine again.